# Centering font awesome icon within a button at all sizes

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I've created a simple button with a font awesome search icon. Just wondering why it isn't always centred. I'd also like the search icon to stay within the middle of the button.

I thought the `text-align` property would work but so far I'm having no luck.

```css
.button {
  width: 5%;
  padding: 2vh 4vh;
  margin: 1vh 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 0.5vh #000000;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" style="text-shadow: 
none;"></i></button>
```

[image: Example of the same button with different viewport widths]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code that you have is centering the icon. I've demonstrated this by including a second button with a width of 50%. As you scale your browser you will be able to see more clearly with the 50% example that the icon is always centered. The only problem with your attempt is that when the browser gets too small the margins and padding are still retained, shifting it over to the right. To fix this, I've changed your width to a minimum width. This maintains all the padding and margins within the button and won't go smaller.If the button needs to be smaller than this, I suggest using media queries to adjust your margin and padding for smaller screens.

```css
.button {
  min-width: 5%;
  padding: 2vh 4vh;
  margin: 1vh 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 0.5vh #000000;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.button2 {
  min-width: 50%;
  padding: 2vh 4vh;
  margin: 1vh 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 0.5vh #000000;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" style="text-shadow: 
none;"></i></button>
<br><br>
<button class="button2" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" style="text-shadow: 
none;"></i></button>
```

Comment: That's more complex? I only need a way of centring it for one button size because it's dependant on viewport scaling.

Comment: Still no luck, any ideas?

Comment: Much simpler solution. Thank you very much. I just didn't understand why it was happening :)

Answer (score 1):

Another nowadays example via Flexbox.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.search {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 6rem;
  border: solid .1rem #006bde;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #006bde;
}

.envira {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: solid .1rem #21b384;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #21b384;
}

.bell {
  width: 7rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: solid .1rem orange;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="flex-container">
  <button class="btn search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button class="btn bell"><i class="fa fa-bell-slash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button class="btn envira"><i class="fa fa-envira" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `display:block; padding:0; width:max-content; margin:auto;` on `<I>` element will do the magic:

```css
.button {
    width: 5%;
    min-width: max-content; 
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    margin: 1vh 0.5;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 0.5vh #000000;
    border-radius: 2vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: bottom
}

.button > i { display:block; padding:0; width:max-content; margin:auto; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="button" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" style="text-shadow: 
none;"></i></button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked. When the browser fills the screen the icon is in the centre. Otherwise the icon floats slightly to the right. Try `Run code snippet` then `Full page` and resize the browser window :)

Comment: still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated code in my answer:  `.button {min-width: max-content;}` is required as in some cases `width:5%` can be smaller than `16px;` of your font-size.